# How to pass parameters dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, parameters

I need to pass the $route to its inner function,but failed:

```
function compilePath( $route )
{
    preg_replace( '$:([a-z]+)$i', 'pathOption' , $route['path'] );
    function pathOption($matches)
    {
        global $route;//fail to get the $route
    }
}
```

I'm using php5.3,is there some feature that can help?

Comment: Can you declare functions inside of functions? Does PHP support anonymous functions?

Comment: @Anthony This is perfectly valid PHP code. However, most people don't actually declare functions within functions.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're a javascript programmer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do anything like that in PHP 5.2, unfortunatly -- but as you are using PHP 5.3... you could use Closures to get that to work.

To begin, here's a quick example of using a Closure :

```
function foo()
{
    $l = "xyz";
    $bar = function () use ($l)
    {
        var_dump($l);
    };
    $bar();
}
foo();
```

Will display :

```
string 'xyz' (length=3)
```

Notice the `use` keyword ;-)

And here's an example of how you could use that in your specific case :

```
function compilePath( $route )
{
    preg_replace_callback( '$:([a-z]+)$i', function ($matches) use ($route) {
        var_dump($matches, $route);
    } , $route['path'] );
}

$data = array('path' => 'test:blah');
compilePath($data);
```

And you'd get this output :

```
array
  0 => string ':blah' (length=5)
  1 => string 'blah' (length=4)

array
  'path' => string 'test:blah' (length=9)
```

A couple of notes :

- I used [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), and not `preg_replace` -- as I want some callback function to be called.
- I'm using an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as callback
- And that anonymous function is importing `$route`, with the new `use` keyword.

  - Which means that, in my callback function, I can access both the matches, which are always passed by `preg_replace_callback` to the callback function, and the `$route`.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in a class, including the callback and grab $route using $this->route instead of using globals. You should be using preg_replace_callback(). To use a callback from a class use Array($class,'callback') or Array('className','callback).